# infinite api calls in componentDidUpdate(prevProps) despite conditional that compares current prop with previous prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

My problem is in my subcomponent files where every state update in the parent component keeps re-rendering the subcomponents infinitely by making infinite api calls with the default or updated props value passed to the child components. I have a User directory page which contains multiple components in a single page.

```js
class Users extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: "",
      listOfUsers: [],
      socialData:[],
      contactData:[],
      videoData:[],
      detailsData:[]
    }
   }

  componentDidMount(){
    //api call that gets list of users here
    //set response data to this.state.listOfUsers
  }
   
   userHandler = async (event) => {
    this.setState({
      user: event.target.value,
    });
   };

   render() {
      return (
       <div>
        <div>
           <select
             value={this.state.user}
             onChange={this.userHandler}
           >
             // list of users returned from api
           </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Social Media user={this.state.user} />
          <Contact user={this.state.user}/>
          <Video user={this.state.user}/>
          <Details user={this.state.user}/>
        </div>
       </div>
      );
    }
}
```

I have 1 API call for the parent component `Users`, and 4 for each of the subcomponents: `Social Media`, `Contact`, `Video`, and `Details`. The `Users` api will return a list of users in a dropdown and the value of the user selected is then fed to the other four API's. i.e. `https://localhost:3000/social_media?user=${this.state.user}`. Thus, the four subcomponents' API is dependent on the `Users` API. I currently have the parent api call in a `componentDidMount()` and the other 4 api calls in their respective subcomponents and use props to pass down the value of the user selected in the parent to the subcomponents. Each of the api calls is in a `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)`. All the subcomponents follow this structure:

```js
class Social Media extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: "",
      socialData:[],
    }
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({ user: this.props.user })
   }
   
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
     if (this.props.user !== prevProps.user) {
       // make api call here
       fetch (`https://localhost:3000/social_media?user=${this.state.user}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((error) => console.error("Error: ", error))
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ socialData: Array.from(data) });
        }
   }

   render() {
      return (
        {this.socialData.length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <Social Media data={this.state.socialData}/>
        </div>
        ) 
        :
        (<div> Loading ... </div>)
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: where is prevProps gettin g set?

Comment: What are `this.props.user` and `prevProps.user` when that check is evaluating to `false`? If I understand what behavior you're observing, those must be differing somehow.

Comment: Doesn't the conditional `this.props.user !== prevProps.user` in `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` set it? Or do I have to set it in a certain way. I just followed the example: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate . @Aaron `this.props.user` is the value passed from the parent component. I updated the original post with that part (sorry it was missing).

Comment: This is likely because of how javascript compares objects. `this.props.user` and `prevProps.user` are shallowly equal, but they do not share the same reference so it evaluates to false

Comment: I understand how it's being passed in, but I mean what exactly are the values at the time of comparison? `console.log(typeof this.props.user, this.props.user, typeof prevProps.user, typeof prevProps.user)` is my go-to.

Comment: as Aaron mentioned, I also think the user property is not a primitive value but something else.

Comment: @Aaron it was a type comparison issue. @WebbH's example of using `shallowEqualObjects` resolved the issue. Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.props.user` is an object, then `this.props.user !== prevProps.user` will evaluate to true because they are not the same object. If you want to compare if they have the same properties and values (i.e. they are shallowly equal) you can use an npm package like [shallow-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallow-equal) and do something like:

```
import { shallowEqualObjects } from "shallow-equal";
//...
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
 if (!shallowEqualObjects(prevProps.user, this.props.user)) {
   // make api call here
   fetch (`https://localhost:3000/social_media?user=${this.state.user}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error: ", error))
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ socialData: Array.from(data) });
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Abortive attempt to answer your question**

It's hard to say exactly what's going on here; based on the `state` shown in the `Users` component, `user` should be a string, which should be straightforward to compare, but clearly something is going wrong in the `if (this.props.user !== prevProps.user) {` comparison.

If we could see the results of the `console.log(typeof this.props.user, this.props.user, typeof prevProps.user, typeof prevProps.user)` call I suggested in my comment, we'd probably have a better idea what's going on here.

**Suggestions that go beyond the scope of your question**

Given the moderate complexity of your state, you may want to use some sort of shared state like React's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), Redux, or MobX.. I'm partial toward the Context API, as it's built into React and requires relatively less setup.

(Then again, I also prefer functional components and [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to classes and `componentDidUpdate`, so my suggestion may not apply to your codebase without a rewrite.)